Adding RoleId and UserId results in: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
I am trying to add the roleId and userId in the User_Roles table, but the post create is shown an error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

This is the modules file for UserRoles.js:
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    const UserRoles = sequelize.define("User_Roles");

    return UserRoles;
}

This is the router file for UserRoles.js:
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const UserRoles = require("../models").UserRoles;

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const { RoleId, UserId } = req.body;
    const usrRoles = await UserRoles.create({ RoleId: RoleId, UserId: UserId });
    res.json(usrRoles);
});

module.exports = router;

On the page where I have an action to add the roleid and userid:
axios.post("http://localhost:3001/userRoles", { RoleId: parseInt(value, 10), UserId: selectedUserIdEdit }).then((response) => {
    console.log('response', response);
})

The console.log shows: RoleId: 1, UserId: 1, which is correct, but it's not storing it.

make sure that the UserRoles model is correctly defined and exported in your Sequelize model file. The model file should look something like this:
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const UserRoles = sequelize.define("UserRoles", {
        RoleId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        UserId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    }, {
        // Additional model options (optional)
        tableName: 'User_Roles', // Specify table name if it's not     automatically inferred
        timestamps: false, // Disable timestamps if not needed
    });

    return UserRoles;
};

Check that the UserRoles model is correctly imported and exported in the models/index.js file, which usually looks like this:
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL); // Adjust based on your config

    const db = {};
    
    db.UserRoles = require('./UserRoles')(sequelize, DataTypes);
    // Import other models as needed
    // db.OtherModel = require('./OtherModel')(sequelize, DataTypes);
    
    db.sequelize = sequelize;
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
    
    module.exports = db;


I have a User and Roles module and an associated User_Roles module. Thats why the User_Roles module has no field set to it. As mentioned in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78934790/roles-not-associated-to-users
